# Whats with this rollover?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I hate fixing stuff after somebody. Especially in wordpress :P.

http://greenteam.com.pl/oferta/

Check out this site. I added second row of buttons (you don't have to know meaning of the words :P). But, as you can see, it gets completely broken when you roll over one of the second row options. I can find anything wrong in .css and I have no idea how this wordpress code works:

```
<?php if (is_tree(6)): //podstrony oferta ?>
<ul id="submenu" class="current_<?= $post->ID ?><?php if (is_page(6)) {echo " main";} ?>">
    <?php wp_list_pages('depth=1&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=6&title_li=') ?>
</ul>
```

Any clues? I'd appreciate any help. Is it wordpress fault? Or is it in .css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), you can see that the height from the link `<a>` changes from 37px to 39px. Because of the floating property, everything shifts to the right of the higher block.

I think it is best to check all your height properties, because it is quite strange to change the height by 2 pixels on a hover event.

```
.oferta #content #submenu li a:hover {
    height: 39px;
}
```

Comment: If this answer satisfies what you are looking for, please press the `accept` button.